# C - Get substring after first n characters of string

Tags: c, string, substring, c-strings

This is proving to be surprisingly hard to do, and I have yet to find a straightforward solution looking through existing questions.  I've looked at several duplicate questions, but they aren't what I'm looking for.

I've tried something like this, but I'm clearly misunderstanding how `strncpy` works.  I want to get **all** of the text **after** the first 14 characters of the string.

```
int length = sizeof(str) - 14;
strncpy(substr, str+14, length);
```

What is the simplest way of doing this?

Comment: Do you maybe mean `int length = strlen(str) - 14;`? I'm supposing that you check that it is at least 15 characters long before.

Comment: What is the declaration of `str`?

Comment: Also, what's wrong with just using `strcpy`? `strcpy(substr, str+14);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tried something like this, but I'm clearly misunderstanding how
>   strncpy works. I want to get all of the text after the first 14
>   characters of the string.

```
int length = strlen(str) - 14;
if(length >= 0) {
   strncpy(substr, str+13, length);
   substr[length] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi, thanks for the suggestion. I have edited the answer.

Comment: The above code does not address the stated goal: *I want to get all of the text **after** the first 14 characters of the string.* It uses `strncpy()` for no reason. It is equivalent to `strcpy(substr, str+13);`, simpler and more readable, but still with the wrong offset.

Comment: @chqrlie, you might want to read between the lines in OP's question. The objective is not just to achieve the goal but to also develop understanding of `strncpy` which my answer tries to provide.

Comment: For this purpose, you would need to write `strncpy(substr, str+14, length);` but it teaches the OP nothing about `strncpy()` as for these arguments, `memcpy()` would be more appropriate.  All the OP needs to know about `strncpy` is here: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/stop-using-strncpy-already/ and here: https://blog.liw.fi/posts/strncpy/

Comment: Btw, no reading between the lines is needed: *I'm clearly misunderstanding how `strncpy` works* is pretty clear! My recommendation about `strncpy` is just as clear: **Do not use it!**.  Read the articles to understand why.

Answer (score 4):

Are you misunderstaing how math works? *10 - 14 = -4*

**EDIT:**

There was a

```
char str[10];
int length = sizeof(str) - 14;
```

int the original post. (*see the edits*)

Also, you should not use `sizeof` to compute the length of a string, use `strlen()`. The `sizeof` operator is used to find out the size of a type, assuming `str` is an array or a pointer `sizeof` will return the number of elements in the first case and the size of a pointer equivalent to `sizeof(void *)` in the second.

A string is an array, but the size of such array is not the length of the string, a string of 10 characters can be stored into an array of 100 elements, so the problem is not `strncpy` (*which you should avoid BTW, because it does not guarantee `nul` termination*), the real problem is how you are handling it.

Suppose you have a valid string of length ≥ 14, then

```
strcpy(substr, str + 14)
```

should be enough!

You should make sure that the target array `substr` is big enough of course and that length of `str` is more than or equal to *14* or, you would in any of both cases invoke undefined behavior.

If you previously know the length of `str` then, you can try

```
memcpy(substr, str + 14, length_str - 14);
substr[length_str - 14] = '\0';
```

note that `substr` must have at least `length_str - 14` elements +1 for the `nul` terminator, and also if you know that there is a `'\0'` terminator in `str`, then

```
// Leaving + 1 explicitly to denote the '\0'
memcpy(substr, str + 14, length_str - 14 + 1);
```

should copy it in a single call.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems in your attempt:

- `sizeof(str)` does not compute the number of characters in the string pointed to by `str`. It evaluates to the size of `str`, which could be a pointer or an array as you did not post the definition. You should use `strlen(str)` for this purpose.
- `strncpy()` **does not do what you think it does**.  This function is very error prone. It is never the right tool for any job, do not use it.

The solution is simple: if you know that `str` has at least 14 characters and `substr` points to an array long enough to receive the rest of the string, just write this:

```
strcpy(substr, str + 14);  // copy all characters, skipping the first 14 bytes
```

If `str` might have less than 14 characters, add a test:

```
*substr = '\0';
if (strlen(str) >= 14) {
    strcpy(substr, str + 14);
}
```

If you know the size of the destination, but do not know if it is large enough to receive the rest of the string, use this:

```
*substr = '\0';
if (strlen(str) >= 14) {
    snprintf(substr, substr_size, "%s", str + 14);
}
```

Or this alternative:

```
*substr = '\0';
if (strlen(str) >= 14) {
    // copy at most substr_size-1 characters from str, skipping the first 14 bytes.
    // and null terminate the destination string.
    strncat(substr, substr_size - 1, str + 14);
}
```